# Qt Widget C++ Autosize to Smaller Screens (SEE SCREENSHOTS)

Tags: c++, qt, screen

I'm very new to QT and am looking for a QT genius to help me figure out how to can my widget automatically resize when I move it to my bigger screen into the smaller one. Please see below.

Widget in Bigger Screen

[image]

PROBLEM: Widget in Smaller Screen

[image]

Comment: I don't know any app that starts resizing itself only by moving it. I'd say: choose a decent size and let the user resize it as it needs.

Comment: To the good advice given by @GuillaumeRacicot, I would add that you should  design your windows for a minimum screen size (you may enforce it), and test if stretching produces good results.